# How to use a uiscrollview inside uitableviews static cell with UITableView.automaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've created a slider like described in here: https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92

Using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2.1

I've got an extra Userinterface View, like in the tutorial, just consisting of a `uiimageview` with 4 contraints:

- safe area bottom = image view bottom
- image view top = safe area top
- image view centerx = superviews centerx
- image view width = superviews width

So its custom class is just:

```
class ImageSlide: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!   
}
```

I've got a storyboard with a Tableview controller. The Table View's content is set to `Static cells` with `automaticDimension`.
Using this constraints for the scroll view

[image]

Controller Lifecycle:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0
    ...
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    setupSlideScrollView(with: slides)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    setupSlideScrollView(with: slides)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // time consuming (pictures fetched over the network)
    slides = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(with: slides)
}
```

```
private func createSlides() -> [ImageSlide] {

    // slides will be fetched over the network
    // testing the scaleAspects
    ...
    slide1.mainImageView.image = ...
    slide1.mainImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    slide2.mainImageView.image = ...
    slide2.mainImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    return [slide1, slide2]
}
```

```
private func setupSlideScrollView(with slides: [ImageSlide]?) {

    sliderScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides?.count ?? 1), height: 300.0)
    sliderScrollView.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300.0)

    if let imageSlides = slides {

        for i in 0..<imageSlides.count {
            imageSlides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 300.0)

            sliderScrollView.addSubview(imageSlides[i])
        }

        print("scroll view frame height: \(sliderScrollView.frame.height)")
        print("scroll view contentsize height: \(sliderScrollView.contentSize.height)")
        print("slides[0] frame height: \(imageSlides[0].frame.height)")

    }

}
```

I'm testing with a hard coded height value of `300.0`. Running this on a iPad pro 12.9-inch 3rd gen, gives me a cell with a height of about 40 or 50. The first slide is stretched over the full width, the second slide is super small adapted to the height (which is expected so far because of scaleAspectFill/scaleAspectFit).
The Log is showing:

```
[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
scroll view frame height: 300.0
scroll view contentsize height: 300.0
slides[0] frame height: 300.0
scroll view frame height: 300.0
scroll view contentsize height: 300.0
slides[0] frame height: 300.0
```

I do have some empty cells in the table view, don't know if the warning is because of them or because of the slider.
When I rotate the device It looks like I do have a height of `300.0` for the given slide, but the cell is way bigger (fills the whole screen).

I don't understand why at the beginning the cell height is around 40 or 50, with the warning message. Why isn't the cell automatically adapting to the specified height of 300? 
For example I would like to say, the slider should always have the height of e.g. `view.frame.height/3`. So should the cell. The Images which I put into the slider should respect `scaleAscpectFill` and fill the whole width. But somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After a break I came up with a solution, actually I'm not sure if it is a solution or a workaround.

I've added a computed property

```
var sliderHeight: CGFloat! {
    get {
        return view.frame.width/2
    }
}
```

and changed

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0, indexPath.row == 0 {
        return sliderHeight
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

respectively changed the `setupSlideScrollView` method to not use the hardcoded height of `300.0` but `sliderHeight`. It still isn't perfect (the page control view is missing, will take a look on that now) but the height of the cell seems to be correct so far.
Btw the warning form the first post also disappeared.
What do you think guys, a proper solution or just a workaround?